# Ubuntu Says bitcoind not installed

Tags: bitcoind

My "best" friend Ubuntu 14 says bitcond is not installed type to install: apt-get install bitcond
I typed.
Succesful installed.
I try open whit this command in terminal/SHH: bitcond -deamon
But Ubuntu say bitcoind is not installed type to install: 
apt-get install bitcond
WTF??
I did not know what the matter?
Please help me guys!

Comment: Run 2 commands: sudo updatedb; locate bitcoind

Comment: It sounds like you need to run `sudo apt-get install bitcoind`

Comment: Did you try running bitcoind before installing it, then installed it, and it still says it's not found?  If so, try `hash -r` in your shell.

Answer (score 1):

It seems there is already a question on bitcointalk forum posted by you to which I have replied.

https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=1843078.new#new

> I think I may know your problem it is bitcoind not bitcond. Perhaps
>   you are writing it as bitcond in your terminal. Try writing bitcoind.
>   Also the deamon spelling is wrong it is daemon not deamon
>
> If that is not the problem and you are typing it correctly in the
>   terminal you might be running the GUI and the daemon at the same time
>   using the same configaration directory.
>
> If you are not doing that also then look the steps below. I followed
>   it and it worked perfectly fine.
>
> Note: Follow exactly the steps. Do not do step 2 before step 1
>
> Step 1: Add the bitcoin ppa repository to your system.
>
> ```
> sudo apt-add-respository ppa:bitcoin/bitcoin
> ```
>
> Step 2 : Update your packages.
>
> ```
> sudo apt update
> ```
>
> Step 3 : Install the bitcoind core daemon
>
> ```
> sudo apt install bitcoind
> ```
>
> Step 4 : Run the daemon
>
> ```
> bitcoind -daemon
> ```
>
> You should recieve a message that bitcon server has started
>   successfully.
>
> To interact with the bitcoin core you will have to use the command :
>   `bitcoin-cli`
>
> To stop the bitcoin core daemon type : `bitcoin-cli stop`
>
> A complete list of commands is avaliable here:
>   https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-reference#rpc-quick-reference